# Custom Tableview to Segue to Different View Controller

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, segue

Is there a way i can tag each individual cell and have them performSegueWithIdentifier to different ViewController?  Currently, the coding only let me got to one tableview (calc).  If i can have each individual cell got to Casing Capacity VC, Open Hole Capacity VC, etc, that would be great.

```
 class searchtechData : UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

        var calculations = [Formulas]()
        var filteredFormulas = [Formulas]()
        override func viewDidLoad() {

            self.calculations = [Formulas(category:"Capacity", name:"Open Hole Capacity"),
                Formulas(category:"Capacity", name:"Casing Capacity"),
                Formulas(category:"Hard", name:"Multiple String Annular Capacity"),
            self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Tableview

```
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell
            var forumulas : Formulas

            if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
                forumulas = filteredFormulas[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                forumulas = calculations[indexPath.row]
            }
            cell.textLabel!.text = forumulas.name
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
            return cell

        }
```

Segue to calc

```
     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("calc", sender: tableView)

        }
```

Comment: If all formulas should be displayed in the same type of view controller, you should segue to one view controller and just pass the data of the specific formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform segue based on Formulas then you must store segue identifier ins Formulas or name segues based on Formulas name. Then in didSelectRow for index path do the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  var forumulas : Formulas

  if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
       forumulas = filteredFormulas[indexPath.row]
     } else {
       forumulas = calculations[indexPath.row]
     }

  self.performSegueWithIdentifier(forumulas.name, sender: tableView)
}
```

Comment: I got it to work, but how do you have it setup so that it will segue to just a few pages instead of individual VC.  Typically, I would normally have it segue to 3-4 predefine VC.  Hope that make sense.